# Astro.JS Display HTML from JSON data content

Tags: html, typescript, astrojs

I have HTML tags within a JSON value, accessed as an Astro `data` collection type. How do I display this HTML using AstroJS? With React, I used dangerouslySetInnerHTML on a div element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Astro components you'd use the [`set:html` directive](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#sethtml) to do this:

```
---
const htmlString = "<p>Some HTML</p>";
---

<div set:html={htmlString} />
```